# The principle of equivalence and skeletal categories

Tags: category-theory, foundations

I find the nLab entry on the "[principle of equivalence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence)" (formerly entitled "evil") hard reading, and in the final end the status of this principle is not at all clear to me.

Is "evil" thinking - of equality between objects - something one only *should* avoid or something one *must* avoid (as a categorist/structuralist)? What "happens" when one forgets to avoid it, what can one run into? Into contradictions or only into something hideous or "unnatural"?

Especially: Why is "evil" thinking allowed for [skeletal categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton)?

Comment: To say that evil thinking "must" be avoided is too dogmatic. There is a time and place for everything, even for distinguishing between equality and isomorphism.

Comment: The question remains: What is the status of the principle of equivalence? Is it just a recommendation? To avoid what?

Comment: "I find the nLab entry [...] hard reading" Me too. But if I remember correctly, the entry was more readable two years ago.